# Automating the Stacking of Graphene

Tags: linux, automation, mobaxterm

I want to automate the stacking of graphene for my college project. The user will give the angle as an input and the Graphene which will be in AA stacking initially, would change to that custom stacking.

I have made the POSCAR, KPOINTS, INCAR of the AA stacked Graphene and done the same for the AB stacked but do not know how to proceed further. How do I take the input and write a program so that the POSCAR changes according to the input? I am using mobaxterm for linux environment on my windows laptop.

Comment: Write requirements for exactly what your program needs to do, choose a language, write the program, then test against the requirements..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.